# How to read csv files and put it in variable to compare with the given value in C#

Tags: c#, csv

CSV File:

[image]

I am passing "6th" Index to get the username..

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\Users\\e3020722\\Downloads\\AdminLoginSearch (5).csv").Select(a => a.Split(','));
            var csv = from line in lines select (line[6].Split(',')).ToList();
            Report.Info(csv.Count<List<String>>().ToString());
            for(int i=0;i<csv.Count<List<String>>();i++){                
            Console.Writeline(csv.First<List<String>>().GetEnumerator().ToString());
           Report.Info(csv.ElementAt<List<String>>(0).ToString());
            }
```

It prints like this.. ElementAT and GetEnumerator both prints type. How to prnt the value?

```
09:31:44    176
09:31:44    System.Collections.Generic.List`1+Enumerator[System.String]
09:31:44    System.Collections.Generic.List`1+Enumerator[System.String]
09:31:44    System.Collections.Generic.List`1+Enumerator[System.String]
09:31:44    System.Collections.Generic.List`1+Enumerator[System.String]
09:31:44    System.Collections.Generic.List`1+Enumerator[System.String]
```

I want to print all Usernames values instead of type..

Comment: you dont need to split in first line

Comment: what location exactly you want to read? all the username or any specific row?

Comment: If I remove split from first Line. 'char' does not contain a definition for 'Split' and no accessible extension method 'Split' accepting a first argument of type 'char' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [FirstDemoProject]csharp(CS1061)

Comment: all the usernames.. basically if i pass, 7 then all the FirstName, 8 then lastname etc

Comment: you can simply do like this 

`var lines = File.ReadAllLines("test.csv");
foreach(string line in lines)
{
    Console.WriteLine(line.Split(',')[5]);
}`

Comment: This is fine . working..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply do it like this, There is no need to write complex code.

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("test.csv");
foreach(string line in lines)
{
     Console.WriteLine(line.Split(',')[5]);
}
```

I am assuming here that you will always have value the columns otherwise it will throw an exception, so please handle accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Some parts of the code seem unnecessary..
Anyway, this *should* work

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\Users\\e3020722\\Downloads\\AdminLoginSearch (5).csv").Select(a => a.Split(','));
        var csv = from line in lines select (line[6].Split(',')).ToList();
        Report.Info(csv.Count<List<String>>().ToString());
        for(int i=0;i<csv.Count<List<String>>();i++){                
        Console.Writeline(csv.First<List<String>>().First().ToString());
       Report.Info(csv.ElementAt<List<String>>(0).ToString());
        }
```

Comment: 10:04:20 176
10:04:20 First Name
10:04:20 First Name
10:04:20 First Name
10:04:20 First Name Prints first line only.. not all the lines on the file